# Is there scientific evidence of bobcats breeding with house cats?

Tags: animal-behaviour, bobcats

I have seen some barn cats that were claimed to be the offspring of female barn cats and a male bobcat (they had bobbed tails).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felid_hybrid#Attempted_or_unconfirmed_hybrids) says that there is circumstantial and anecdotal evidence for this, but the note says that the source for that information is unreliable, and the date on the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felid_hybrid#cite_note-3) is 1975.

Is there any more recent scientific evidence on whether bobcats can breed with house cats?

Comment: www.ancestry.cat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sadly, No.**  The Pixie Bob is the primary candidate for bobcat/domestic cat interbreeding, but, according to the website of [The Tabaxi Cattery](http://www.tabaxipixiebob.com/pixiebob.php5), which is a breeder of Pixie-Bobs:

> Pixie Bobs are a domestic cat breed with a resemblance to Bobcats,
>   which originated in the Pacific Northwest region of the United States.
>   **Pixie Bobs are not genetically related to Bobcats and this has been
>   proven via DNA testing**.  Bobcats were not used as breeding stock in
>   establishing the beautiful, wonderfully personable Pixie Bob breed,
>   and reputable Pixie Bob breeders have not (and will not) use Bobcats
>   in their breeding programs.  You may notice some Pixie Bob breeders
>   touting their Pixie Bob cats and Pixie Bob kittens as being descended
>   from "original Northwest lines".  Since the breed originated in the
>   Northwest, all Pixie Bobs are descended from "original Northwest lines.  (emphasis added)

According to an article *Eight Cat Breeds with Wild* Roots in the website of [Mental Floss](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51250/8-cat-breeds-wild-roots), all domestic cat breeds with wild roots derive from only three wild cats: the African Serval, the Asian Leopard Cat (which gave rise to the Bengal breed), and the Jungle Cat (Felis Chaus).  The Bengal was used in the breeding of several wild-looking cats, such as the Toyger.  (I don't know how authoritative Mental Floss is.)

Of course, all domestic cats (felis catus) are descended from wild ancestors, principally Felis sylvestris lybica. [International Cat Care](https://icatcare.org/advice/cat-care/origins-cats) says:

> Genetic analysis has demonstrated that the DNA of modern day domestic
>   cats throughout the world is almost identical to that of Felis
>   sylvestris lybica, clearly showing that it is this species that gave
>   rise to our domestic cats.

I remember reading in a reputable journal that Felis chaus may have contributed to Felis catus, but I cannot track down a reference now.